# how to get host IP and port number on which the application is running using javascript

Tags: javascript, ip, port

can anyone tell me how to get host IP and port number on which the web application is running using javascript (e.g. 127.0.0.1:8080)

Comment: you mean the one it was downloaded from?  Webapps "run" on the local browser.

Comment: ya.. the one from it was downloaded.

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid it's not possible to directly obtain the IP address via Javascript.  It's not exposed in the `window.location` object.

Part of the reason for that is that subsequently accessing `address:port` is not semantically the same as accessing `hostname:port` - they are technically different URLs.

If what you're actually after is the host portion of the URL from which the current webapp was downloaded, you need:

```
window.location.hostname
window.location.port
```

The latter could be blank if the "default" port is being used, so you would also need to read:

```
window.location.protocol
```

and check whether it's `http:` (i.e. port 80) or `https:` (port 443).

You can also use:

```
window.location.host
```

which will contain both the `hostname` and the `port` as colon-separated strings, with the same caveat as above that the `:port` section will be omitted if the content was accessed via the "default" port for the protocol.

Comment: thanks for rply.
when i use window.location.hostname, it displays the hostname like localhost, but i need actual ip address like 127.0.0.1

Comment: @user1455802 I did wonder, as your question was confusing as to which you wanted (you said "address", but specified "localhost").  I'm afraid you can't get the IP address directly from Javascript.

Comment: actually the problem is when my application is deployed at some ip eg. 127.16.1.247, my websocket works fine. But when I provide this IP a hostname like sample.something.com, websocket does not work

Auction.initialize = function() {
    Auction.connect('ws://' + window.location.host + '/HTML5/bidforanything/');
    };

Comment: web application is using the default port 8085. So using window.location.host, it is coming blank. I dont want to hard code 8085 in javascript. How can i get port number?..plz help

Comment: @user1455802 how is 8085 the "default"?

Answer (score 6):

```
document.location.host      // localhost:1234
document.location.hostname  // localhost
document.location.port      // 1234
```

Comment: thanks for rply.
when i use document.location.host, it displays the hostname like localhost, but i need actual ip address like 127.0.0.1

Comment: There is no way to look up the ip using only javascript. You could, however, use ajax to poll some kind of webservice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: From the example the user provided, I think document.location.host will work.  I'm assuming that 127.0.0.1:8080 is the url that they are using and trying to get; rather than determining the ip the url resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers by [Eric Lennartsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15717/eric-lennartsson) and [Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak), you can also use

```js
window.location.protocol
```

to get the http protocol that has been used.

`window` being a global variable you can omit window while referring `location`.

All combined you can get the total IP address by running

```js
var url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
console.log(url);
```

Head over to the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/protocol) for more info.