# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400? And my website was JUST fine a week ago

Tags: websocket, socket.io, openshift, webrtc, redhat

I have a websocket app that uses socket.io and webrtc. I have been using openshift free hosting lately, and I haven't been getting what I want out of it. At first, my app works for maybe a few days, maybe a week. And then later on, my app starts saying Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400. So, a week it works, and then a week later, it's giving me an error and doesn't work.

What the heck is going on?

Comment: Are you using ws:// or wss://?

Comment: Try using the IP address instead of the hostname. It worked for me before. That's the last trick in my "WS Handshake Bag"

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it's possible to get the host's ip address via javascript, as said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600244/how-to-get-host-ip-and-port-number-on-which-the-application-is-running-using-jav

Comment: I meant to enter the IP address directly in your JavaScript code.

Comment: I don't think my server gives out an ip address... I am using openshift, and all it has is the cname, which is basically the location url.

Comment: Are you using port 8000 for the url like this ws://<app>-<domain>.rhcloud.com:8000 ?