# ReactJS access to two different subnets

Tags: node.js, networking

I have a ReactJS web app that runs on a local network, but is also accessible via a DMZ'd address to a larger local network. The backend is a node server on that LAN, and I realized it will also have to be exposed so browsers on the broader network can get at it.

What is a good way of handling IP addresses depending on which network the user is on dynamically? Users in the LAN would have to have their browsers aimed at `192.168.x.x`, say, while broader network users would have to point at `10.72.x.x`, as an example, and I don't have a good idea of how to handle this on the fly.

EDIT: I can use something like [ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip) to check my subnet and adjust accordingly, I suppose...not sure this is a best practice.

EDIT 2: I think that maybe I'm not being clear enough from the comments, so here's a little more info:

From the LAN perspective, I need the browser to hit the server at `192.168.25.31`, say. And from the DMZ perspective, I need the browser to hit the server at its broader address, `10.72.10.31`, for example. The two addresses are known, and static. What I need to be able to do in React is select the correct one of the two based on which subnet said browser is on.

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted to be closed, or why the reactjs tag was removed in an edit. It is a reactjs problem with  a clear path to solution, not an open or unanswerable question. I suppose it can be argued that the problem belongs to client-side technologies in general, but may as well tag it with the one it is written in.

Comment: The underlying issue relates to IP routing rather than React. The client source IP is irrelevant to React. The React site exists at a single destination IP. Clients won't hit the site unless there is an IP route to the web server from the client network. That's true if the client is on a 10., 192., or on the Internet. IP routing issues are handled at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com, among other places. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, appreciate the time, but this is not an IP routing question. It is a JavaScript known-IP address-handling programming question.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what you need React to do? I keyed in on "have their browsers aimed at..." which led me to believe it was an IP issue. Thx

Comment: Sure, maybe I'm not being as clear as I could be. I'll edit the question, thanks.

Comment: The fact that you're using React has nothing to do with your question and the problems you're facing.

Comment: The quickest solution would be for you to use a domain name and let the DNS deal with the IP address in the background.

Comment: I can have a DNS reroute the request to the server from one side of the firewall, but not both. That suggestion unfortunately doesn't address the issue. I will agree that it is not a React-specific issue, it is a front-end client-side Javascript issue, so I'll give you that. I think now we're just getting into some odd semantics battle here, however, so I'm just going to leave the question be with your edit and find some other solution.

Comment: You could add the `javascript` tag, but there's already [questions that address IP and port in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12600244/1218980) and it's not really a viable solution to explore. It would be more productive to take a step back and consider solutions that doesn't involve JS guessing the backend IP.